# $\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty} y(x)$ exists and is finite for a solution to an IVP.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I was working on a problem where it stated to show that the solution to

$$y'(x) = \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$$

with $y(0)=y_0$ for $y_0 \neq 0$ satisfies its limit at infinity being finite, that is,
$\displaystyle\lim_{x-> \infty} y(x)$ exists and is finite.

My idea was to first note that $y$ must be increasing, and therefore $y(x) >y_0$ for all $x>0$. So that we may find an upper solution $v(x)$ because

$$\frac{1}{x^2+y^2} < \frac{1}{x^2 + (y_0)^2}$$ so the upper solution would satisfy

$v'(x) = \displaystyle\frac{1}{x^2+(y_0)^2}$, $v(0)=y_0$. This has the solution 
$v(x) = y_0 + \arctan{x}$. So that $y(x) < y_0 + \arctan{x}$, hence we at least know 
$$y_0<\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}y(x) < y_0 + \frac{\pi}{2}$$.

Is this enough of a proof to make the conclusion? Might there be an easier way? Can we get better bounds or maybe even compute the limit explicitly?

Comment: Your approach looks valid (and simple enough), to me at least. To conclude the limit exists, I would argue in more detail that it is an increasing function upper bounded by $\frac{\pi}{2}+y_0$, and thus converging (you introduce the quantity $\lim_\infty y$a bit too early for my taste, as its existence is not immediate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly shown that

$$y_0 < y(x) < y_0 + \pi/2$$

for $x>0$. Now you should argue that $y$ is bounded and monotone, so $\lim_{x \to \infty} y(x)$ must exist and be finite.

Comment: Ah, I see. to which it is monotone as the derivative is always positive. I just needed to piece existence together at the end.